# Mingw64 from msys2 creates corrupt executable

Tags: c++, assembly, mingw-w64, msys2

I am currently using *MSYS_NT-10.0-22621 Legion 3.4.7.x86_64 2023-07-14 16:57 UTC x86_64 Msys*
and using mingw64

My mingw64 version is

```
g++.exe (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I wrote a simple main.cpp file which contained.

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
}
```

However, while building it, even though it creates a *.exe* file, it doesn't output anything.

So, I install a previous version, using Mingw Natively.
And my version was

```
g++.exe (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 12.3.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

For Comparison, I compiled the same file into assembly.

12.3.0

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .text
.lcomm _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC0:
    .ascii "Hello world\0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
.LFB1991:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    __tcf_0;    .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   __tcf_0
__tcf_0:
.LFB2524:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii;    .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
.LFB2523:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, 24(%rbp)
    cmpl    $1, 16(%rbp)
    jne .L6
    cmpl    $65535, 24(%rbp)
    jne .L6
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    leaq    __tcf_0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    atexit
.L6:
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    _GLOBAL__sub_I_main;    .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB2525:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    $65535, %edx
    movl    $1, %ecx
    call    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .ctors,"w"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .ident  "GCC: (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 12.3.0"
    .def    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    atexit; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .rdata$.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, "dr"
    .globl  .refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    .linkonce   discard
.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_:
    .quad   _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    .section    .rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout, "dr"
    .globl  .refptr._ZSt4cout
    .linkonce   discard
.refptr._ZSt4cout:
    .quad   _ZSt4cout
```

And the 13.1 outputs

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .text
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC0:
    .ascii "Hello world\0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
.LFB2073:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section .rdata,"dr"
_ZNSt8__detail30__integer_to_chars_is_unsignedIjEE:
    .byte   1
_ZNSt8__detail30__integer_to_chars_is_unsignedImEE:
    .byte   1
_ZNSt8__detail30__integer_to_chars_is_unsignedIyEE:
    .byte   1
    .ident  "GCC: (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0"
    .def    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .rdata$.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, "dr"
    .globl  .refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    .linkonce   discard
.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_:
    .quad   _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    .section    .rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout, "dr"
    .globl  .refptr._ZSt4cout
    .linkonce   discard
.refptr._ZSt4cout:
    .quad   _ZSt4cout
```

My command was same for the both version, (without any optimisation option)

```
g++ .\main.cpp -S
```

for executable

```
g++ .\main.cpp -o .\main.exe
```

Using `pacman -Qq | grep gcc` in msys2shell, mingw64shell and ucrt64shell,
I get these packages

```
gcc-libs
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-ada
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-objc
mingw-w64-x86_64-libgccjit
```

*Same for all the shells*

When I ran `$ pacman -Qi gcc-libs` in the shell it returned:

```bash
Name            : gcc-libs
Version         : 11.3.0-4
Description     : Runtime libraries shipped by GCC
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://gcc.gnu.org/
Licenses        : GPL  LGPL  FDL  custom
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : None
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : brotli  bsdtar  file  inetutils  libasprintf  libassuan  libbz2  libdb  libexpat  libgdbm
                  libgettextpo  libgnutls  libiconv  libintl  libksba  liblz4  libnghttp2  libnpth  libpcre  libpcre2_8
                  libutil-linux  libzstd  ncurses  wget  zlib  zstd
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 5.30 MiB
Packager        : CI (msys2/msys2-autobuild/79096b75/5113523851)
Build Date      : Mon, May 29, 2023 10:03:27 PM
Install Date    : Tue, Jul 18, 2023 9:15:05 AM
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

Also, for more information, I'm adding this:

```
$ pacman -Qi | grep gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libbz2  libiconv  libexpat  liblzma  liblz4  libopenssl  libzstd  zlib
Depends On      : gcc-libs  zlib  libbz2  liblzma  libzstd
Name            : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libintl  libreadline  ncurses
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libgpg-error
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libreadline  libiconv  libintl  ncurses
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libidn2  libiconv  libintl  gmp  libnettle  libp11-kit  libtasn1  zlib
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libintl
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libiconv
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libgpg-error
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libintl
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils  mingw-w64-x86_64-crt  mingw-w64-x86_64-headers  mingw-w64-x86_64-isl  mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv  mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc  mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs=13.1.0-7  mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest  mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib  mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs=13.1.0-7
Name            : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr  mingw-w64-x86_64-ncurses  mingw-w64-x86_64-python  mingw-w64-x86_64-readline  mingw-w64-x86_64-xxhash  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib  mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-expat  mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-gettext
Required By     : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-expat  mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2  mingw-w64-x86_64-libffi  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpdecimal  mingw-w64-x86_64-ncurses  mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl  mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3  mingw-w64-x86_64-tcl  mingw-w64-x86_64-tk  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib  mingw-w64-x86_64-xz  mingw-w64-x86_64-tzdata
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-termcap
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-readline  mingw-w64-x86_64-tcl  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libiconv  libidn2  libintl  libgpgme  libpcre2_8  libpsl  libuuid  libgnutls  zlib
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Depends On      : gcc-libs  libzstd

nurpr@Legion MSYS ~
$ pacman -Qi | grep mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils  mingw-w64-x86_64-crt  mingw-w64-x86_64-headers  mingw-w64-x86_64-isl  mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv  mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc  mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs=13.1.0-7  mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest  mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib  mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs=13.1.0-7
Name            : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr  mingw-w64-x86_64-ncurses  mingw-w64-x86_64-python  mingw-w64-x86_64-readline  mingw-w64-x86_64-xxhash  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib  mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-expat  mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-gettext
Required By     : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-expat  mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2  mingw-w64-x86_64-libffi  mingw-w64-x86_64-mpdecimal  mingw-w64-x86_64-ncurses  mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl  mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3  mingw-w64-x86_64-tcl  mingw-w64-x86_64-tk  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib  mingw-w64-x86_64-xz  mingw-w64-x86_64-tzdata
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-termcap
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-readline  mingw-w64-x86_64-tcl  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs  mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
Depends On      : mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs
```

Running executable generated from 13.1 outputs nothing where, 12.3 executable outputs correctly. It used to work before I updated it. I also used same version of Mingw natively, and it had the same problem.

**Is it some sort of bug in *g++ 13.1*. Why isn't it working?**

Comment: IIRC executables compiled by the "Built by MSYS2 project" gcc depend on the correct DLLs being present in the PATH so they normally will only work in the MSYS2 shell that sets your PATH correctly, while executables compiled by the MinGW gcc do not have such dependencies. The version is a red herring probably. To recap, the MSYS2 gcc and the MinGW gcc are two different products,

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I downloaded and install the mingw 13.1 natively and still had the problem. I want to use msys2, as it makes a lot of things easier, however, as far as I know, I can't use a old version in msys2

Comment: Fully updated as of today `"g++.exe (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0"` and I had no issue compiling or running your code. Have you fully updated your Msys2 install? (`pacman -Syu`)?

Comment: ***However, while building it, even though it creates a .exe file, it doesn't output anything.*** I expect your problem is related to dlls and the gcc runtime dlls.  Did you run in the mingw64 terminal? If not do you have the `bin` folder of MinGW in your PATH environment variable? If you do make sure that no other folder in your PATH has the gcc runtime dlls. Windows will stop looking at the first match of the dll with the same name. It searches the PATH folders from top to left to right stopping on the first name match for each of the required dlls.

Comment: That can be problematic if other software (of any kind) in your system uses MinGW runtime dlls and is using a different version.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes I did fully update and upgraded it, with this command `pacman -Su && pacman -Syu`. And I also reinstalled everything from scratch,*(both mingw64 native and with msys2)*. But still having the problem with the particular version

Comment: @drescherjm I did add it in the `path`, just so you know. I also reinstalled everything, still had the same issue, with the particular version. However, it runs fine on 12.3

Comment: I notice you have the `ucrt` flavor (Universal C Runtime) as well as `mingw_64` installed. That's fine, I've got both as well. The `ucrt` library will produce smaller binaries, but I would suspect it would also create different assembly than the standard `mingw_64` version. Try building from the `mingw_64` version (blue or purple icon) and then try again with the `ucrt` version (pale yellow-gold icon). Let me know if either work or if you see differences in one working and one not.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I used the `mingw_64` client to compile and had the same output as before. And `ucrt64` doesn't recognise `g++` or `gcc` as any command.
I feel like, the problem is with the mingw64 itself not the msys2 container, as installing the same version of `mingw64` natively also have the same problem in my device

Comment: All that means is you don't have the `gcc` package installed for the `ucrt`. For every `mingw-w64-x86_64...` package for MinGW you have, you should have a corresponding `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64...` package for `ucrt`, e.g.  `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` and  `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc`. I suspect you may have a bit of a mixed install that is causing problems. Check to make sure you have the packages you need. Unless I need the POSIX functions or Linux specific functions, I'll use ucrt. With your code, it produces a `19K` executable. That's good compared to the `mingw-w64-x86_64...` (same optimizations)

Comment: (or `g++` in your case with C++)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I'm sorry but I didn't get what exactly do I need to do in order to fix it. Will reinstalling the whole thing fix it?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Take a look at the `gcc` versions on your install (e..g `pacman -Qq | grep gcc`)  Now compare the ucrt packages wtih the plain mingw ones. Just `pacman -S ....` any missing packages for ucrt or plain mingw or vice-versa. You should have `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc` and `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-libs` for ucrt and `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` and `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs` for plain mingw. (you will need to `binutils` package for both for the `ld` linker.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I updated my question, again, would you mind checking it again please? (at the end section), Thanks

Comment: I don't have a `gcc-libs` (unless that is there as a Title). If not, what is it? `pacman -Qi gcc-libs` and see what it says. That may be a bit part of the problem.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I also added the thing that you asked for in the question.

Comment: This is where I think a lot of the problem starts, you have `gcc-libs` (version `11.3.0-4`) and then both `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc-libs` and `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs` (version `13.1.0-7`) Having mixed library versions for gcc on your system is going to break things. Do the same `pacman -Qi` for them and see if they provide the same dependencies. If so, remove `gcc-libs`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but mingw-toolchain installed it by itself as I ran this command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I also added the thing that you asked  in  the question. Please do check it

Comment: My bad, you are fine with `gcc-libs`, the 11.3 version is just a result of how they package the various utilities. Installing the toolchain the way you did is fine. I'm perplexed. Msys2 has always just worked. Your sample program isn't the issue. Do you do anything strange in your `.bashrc`, environment variables, etc? The only thing you do different is use the windows-stye back-slashes. Do this, compile simply as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp` (the `-O2` being "-Big Oh 2" not "-zero 2").  Then `main.exe` (no slashes)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin again, I don't think it is Msys2. It might be the particular version of port of the g++ compiler (Mingw) itself, as it gives me the same problem while using natively

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin And, would You mind upvoting my question, (if you think the question is worth it) so that I get a bit of reach and get the necessary help I need

Comment: "I am currently using `MSYS_NT-10.0-22621 Legion 3.4.7.x86_64` ..." I suspect you are right about it being an issue with that specific port. We have exhausted my general Msys2 troubleshooting. When I get to this point, it's time to open a issue on [GitHub - Msys2](https://github.com/sponsors/msys2) and get specific help from those who maintain that port. It may be something has changed on the Windows side in one of the latest updates (there was an update to .NET that installed today when I started a windows box to troubleshoot your issue). The Win10 builds are working, so NT may be the cause.

Comment: Try `g++ .\main.cpp -o .\main.exe -static`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thanks for being with me here. I am new to this. Should I create an issue in the Github repo? Which repo should I report this to? What things should I mention there?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin should I contact the maintainers?

Comment: Yep, that's what I do when I've exhausted my reasonable inquiry into why X doesn't work like it should. Create a GitHub account if you don't have one. The open an "Issue" at the link in my comment. You can paste the URL of this question into your issue showing the investigation you have done. The Msys2 devs are good about helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had Qt install and apparently that was messing up with my mingw64.
The windows `system path` in environmental variable also had qt directory before the msys2 itself.

After Uninstalling qt and removing it from `system path` fixed this issue.